# cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm struggling to understand why this query doesn't work. Similar queries work just fine when not using `Select`, but when I use `Select` nothing works:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Books> Get()
{
     using(var context = new SchoolContext())
     {
          return context.Books.Select(s => new { s.Boknummer, s.Arstall}).ToList();
     }    
}
```

Comment: `new { s.Booknummer, s.Arstall }`  What makes you think that is a `Book`?

Comment: Why not use `return context.Books.ToList();`?

Comment: As mjwills says, the return type of your method is defined as IEnumerable<Books>, but you're trying to return a list of anonymous objects.

Comment: You keep mentioning you want to select specific rows, but in your code you're selecting specific _columns_. What do you really want?

Comment: @Orion, sorry for the inconsistency. I now understand. This is my first time using #C and API.net core web api. Im very new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return strong typed value with just a few fields of a larger class, you need do create a ViewModel class.

You were telling to your code that your controller action was expecting to return a `List<Book>` but you were providing an anonymous object built by LINQ. When you do a `Select(s => new {})` the code doesn't have a type to fit this content, so it is considered an anonymous type.

To achieve the expected result, do the following

Create a ViewModel that will be used to type your return

```
public class BooksLightViewModel
{
   public string Boknummer { get; set; }
   public string Arstall { get; set; }
}
```

Then write your controller action like this

```
[HttpGet]

public IEnumerable<BooksLightViewModel> Get()
{
    using(var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        return context.Books.Select(s => new BooksLightViewModel { 
                                                      Boknummer = s.Boknummer, 
                                                      Arstall = s.Arstall
                                                  }).ToList();
    }    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Now I understand a lot more. I Really appericate this.

Comment: @name, mark this answer as a question answer.